# Sharepoint central administration not showing

Tags: sharepoint

I have just installed sharepoint server 2010 and the products configuration wizard.
Installation was successful but I cant get the central administration to open up.
Tried running products configuration wizard again but doesn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get to open up"? What are you getting when you try?

Comment: I just get a blank page and I have tried to enable authentication using the command on this page- http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2010/06/getting-blank-page-instead-of-central.html

But I cant get the windows, basic authentication to appear in IIS